# Spawning noise-based fire effect with code, no prefabs

Tags: unity, c#, shaders, graphic-effects

i'm a beginner in Unity, and I'm taking a Graphics course about algorithms of procedural textures/modeling.

I would like to write a [noise-based fire shader like this one](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Fire-rendered-with-Perlin-noise-left-and-Simplex-noise-right_fig4_221257826):

[image: Fire effect example]

I would like to then be able to spawn an instance of this effect without using a prefab.

For reference, [the
current effects in my game look like this](https://streamable.com/okiz4u), using prefabs. My instructor has asked me to create the effects purely using algorithms and code, without prefabs.

Comment: Looks like you just need to create a quad dynamically, such as with [GameObject.CreatePrimitive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CreatePrimitive.html), then assign it a material you've made that uses your noise-based fire shader. Which step would you like help with? Creating the primitive? Assigning the material? Or writing the noise-based fire shader? Please edit your question to focus on this specifically. Your edits don't need to append onto the end of the question — you can completely re-write the title and body to focus on your refined topic.

Comment: Done editing of the question. i would like to know how to create primitives and write noise-based fire/ice/lighting/smoke/etc shaders

Comment: I've edited your question to show you what format you should be using here. Remember, we cannot tell you how to make "fire/ice/lightning/smoke/etc" shaders all in one answer — that's too much to answer all at once, and each one will use different techniques. Now, I've shown you via the link in the comment above how to create primitives in Unity, and from the linked fire example you shared, it seems you've already found research papers demonstrating how to write fire shaders with noise. So it seems you have all the ingredients you need. How have you put these ingredients together so far?

Comment: Actually i did, thank you!

Comment: You did what? Did you solve your problem? If so, please post your solution as an Answer below.

Comment: https://unitylist.com/browse?f=procedural
Here there are many implementions those effects, hope it helps others!

Comment: Please post an answer if your problem is solved. Not a comment. Not a link.